# Developing GIS application for windows phone 7 and 8

Tags: sql-server, windows-phone-7, geospatial

I am planing to start a GIS application for windows phone (7 and 8) and I have some important questions. Any idea will be appreciated!

1- Database Engine for WinPhone. Is SQLServer Compact the only option for database engine? Is there an alternative?

2- Does SQLServer Compact (or its alternative) support Spatial data?

3- Is there any libraries suitable for works like processing geo-spatial data? Rendering such data?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Compact is the built-in database for Windows Phone. However, if you can find other C#-based databases, they can probably be made to work.

I would expect any GIS library to be commercial. See for example [Map Suite](http://gis.thinkgeo.com/Products/GISComponentsforNETDevelopers/MapSuiteWindowsPhoneEdition/tabid/896/Default.aspx) which is a Windows Phone GIS component.

You might be able to use some of the code from http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/ - but it targets .NET4.0 rather than Windows Phone.